# Autocomplete not working after using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-autocomplete

[image: Initial Page]

[image: After click on add button it will enabled book code textbox and when i enter 2 key it will populate table below]

[image: After that when press keydown from book code textbox it will focus on table row and after i press enter on row it will populate in book code and book type textboxes and after focus is move on book name textbox]

[image: Book name textbox i implemented keyup js functionality to move focus on book code textbox but, issue is here after that when i press 2 on book code textbox it must be populate table but it not populate]

Can any one help me why the autocomplete not working after the first time it used

my code is here

```
$(document).on("keydown", "#ContentPlaceHolder1_TxtBookName", function (e) {
        if (e.which == 38) {
            var editMode = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnEdit");
            if (editMode.val() != "true") {
                var submit = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_BtnSubmit").attr("disabled");
                var add = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_Btnadd").attr("disabled");
                var cancel = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_BtnCancel").attr("disabled");
                if (submit == undefined && add == "disabled" && cancel == undefined) {
                    $(ContentPlaceHolder1_txtBookCode2).val(null);
                    $(ContentPlaceHolder1_txtBookType).val(null);                        $(ContentPlaceHolder1_txtBookCode2).removeAttr("disabled");
                    $(ContentPlaceHolder1_txtBookType).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    $(ContentPlaceHolder1_txtBookCode2).focus();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why are you checking for the up-arrow key? `if (e.which == 38)`

Comment: if the data is selected wrong so we need to go back on book code textbox and do same process again for right data

Comment: you have any idea about this?